Interpretation of ICC and Pearson's r correlation
I am calculating intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) values for response values at two different timepoints. I am also correlating the response values at the different timepoints using Pearson's $r$. The values are coming out almost identical. Does this conceptually make sense?

Short answer: Yes. I'll write a longer answer if I have time later (and I remember and no one else does it first).
